# Mostrar informacion dependiendo del usuario de la base de datos

Tags: php, html

Estoy creando un simple proyecto de cuenta, pero mi unico problema es que quiero que se muestre informacion especifica dependiendo del usuario.

Ejemplo:

Usuario: Su trabajo este blabla /
Usuario2: No tiene ningun trabajo disponible por el momento

Como puedo hacer que se muestre diferente informacion dependiendo del usuario?

config:

```html
<?php
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_NAME', 'users');

$link = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
 
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: No se pudo conectar. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
```

index

```html
<?php


session_start();
 
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
    header("location: login.php");
    exit;
}


?>
 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Bienvenido</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        body{ font: 14px sans-serif; text-align: center; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Hola, <b><?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["username"]); ?></b></h1>
        <p>
            
        
            
        </p>

    </div>
    <p>
        <a href="resetear.php" class="btn btn-warning">resetea tu clave</a>
        <a href="salir.php" class="btn btn-danger">salir de la cuenta</a>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No se entiende tu duda, si pudieras expresarlo mejor ayudaría a que recibas mejor apoyo

Comment: usuario de la configuración de la base de datos? de una tabla? de un qué?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que tienes una tabla llamada `users` y que tiene dos usuarios registrados.

```
----------------------------
| id | nombre |  trabajo   |
----------------------------
| 1  | lalo   | Ingeniero  | 
| 2  | dani   | Arquitecto |
----------------------------
```

Bastimente la consulta que vas a realizar es un `SELECT`, si el usuario se logueo con el `id` con valor `1` entonces haces la consulta:

```
$id = 1; // Aquí defines la variable que contiene el id del usuario
$sql = "SELECT nombre,trabajo FROM users WHERE id = ".$id;
if ($resultado = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
    if ($resultado->num_rows === 0){
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = $resultado->fetch_assoc();
    }
}
```

En tú **HTML** ya imprimes los datos:

```
<div class="page-header">
    <h1>Hola, <b><?= $_SESSION['usuario']['nombre'] ?></b> tu trabajo es: <?= $_SESSION['usuario']['trabajo'] ?></h1>
</div>
```